# Custom data-role=page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

Right now I am navigating pages using the `data-role=page` which means that the page targets other pages with `"page"` as their data-role.

Is it possible to `navigate using a custom data-role` that has similar function of "page" like say, subpage?

Please do enlighten me on how to do this. Thank you! So basically, `main-2` should transition to `inner-page-2`, the same way `main` transitions to `inner-page-1`.

```
<div id="main" data-role="page">
 content goes here
</div>

<div id="inner-page-1" data-role="page">
 content goes here
</div>

<div id="main-2" data-role="subpage">
 content goes here
</div>

<div id="inner-page-2" data-role="subpage">
 content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: how do you perform your navigation in code?

Comment: Edited my question to illustrate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [jQuery Mobile Subpage Widget](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) plugin.

Usage:

`Add a stack of child div's with data-role="subpage" or data-role="subpage-dialog" to a parent div with data-role="page"`

Comment: My subpage isn't under a parent div though.